# Where should I put uploaded files in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, collectionfs

I'm creating a web app using meteorjs that uploads files on server (I'm not using any package), what does contain the `.meteor/build` folder ? and where should I put uploaded files ? on `server\files` or `.meteor\local\build\programs\server\files` ?

Comment: It is typically recommended when dealing with web apps to never put user provided uploads/content in the same path as your application code.  You most definitely do not want to use the .meteor folder at all.  That folder is used strictly by the meteor app/build tools to do their processing, and adding/updating files there could have undesired consequences.

Comment: even if I put files in server\files wich is accesible only by server ?

Comment: It is true that putting stuff in `server/files` is only accessible to the server, but in general web apps putting ANYTHING in your apps folder structure is usually avoided due to injection problems.  For instance, if I had a web app I could upload a file with the name `../../methods/myHackedMeteorMethods.js` and potentially overwrite your app code with my own code.  Again, this is only an example, but that's why we typically don't let users upload to our app location.  It's better to have a separate place that only the app user can write to, or some store to the DB as a pretend file system.